# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start > master java.io.IOException: CRC check failed

Tags: apache, hbase, apache-zookeeper

i'm trying to use the HBase shell. To do that i just launch the command list. When i do that it appears this:

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: null
```

I checked the hbase-ubuntu-master-localdomain.log and it says:

> **mer 26 mar 2014, 11.03.23**, CET Starting master on ubuntu-linux ulimit
>   -n 10000 2014-03-26 11:03:24,932 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.2-1031432, built on 11/05/2010 05:32
>   GMT
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,932** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:host.name=localhost
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,932** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:java.version=1.7.0_25
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,932** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,932** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,932** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:java.class.path=/home/ubuntu...........CONTINUE
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,933** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,933** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,933** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:java.compiler=
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,933** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:os.name=Linux
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,933** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:os.arch=amd64
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,933** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:os.version=3.8.0-19-generic
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,933** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:user.name=ubuntu
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,933** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:user.home=/home/ubuntu
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,933** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server
>   environment:user.dir=/home/ubuntu/programs/hbase-0.90.0
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:24,951** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Created server with
>   tickTime 2000 minSessionTimeout 4000 maxSessionTimeout 40000 datadir
>   /home/ubuntu/hbaseStore/zookeeper/zookeeper/version-2 snapdir
>   /home/ubuntu/hbaseStore/zookeeper/zookeeper/version-2
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:25,103** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: binding to port
>   0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:26,746** INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap: Reading snapshot
>   /home/ubuntu/hbaseStore/zookeeper/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.77c034
>
> **2014-03-26 11:03:27,430** ERROR
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start
>   master java.io.IOException: CRC check failed
>
> at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.next(FileTxnLog.java:561)
>
> at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.init(FileTxnLog.java:479)
>
> at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.(FileTxnLog.java:454)
>
> at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog.read(FileTxnLog.java:325)
>
> at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:126)
>
> at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:197)
>
> at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.loadData(ZooKeeperServer.java:239)
>
> at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.startdata(ZooKeeperServer.java:366)
>
> at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$Factory.startup(NIOServerCnxn.java:160)
>
> at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MiniZooKeeperCluster.startup(MiniZooKeeperCluster.java:118)
>
> at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:125)
>
> at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:102)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>
> at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:1071)

Anyone knows what's the problem here ?
ps. i'm using HBase+zookeeper standalone just on my PC

Comment: what does output of jps says? does it show HMaster. Also post your "hbase-site.xml" from the conf folder

Comment: Can you put down the commands you used for starting hbase and zookeeper..

Comment: When i'm in the HBase directory i write `./bin/start-hbase.sh`. To start ZooKeeper i go on bin directory and i write `sudo ./hbase-daemon.sh start zookeeper` .

Comment: can you take a look at my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663484/get-error-cant-get-master-address-from-zookeeper-znode-data-null-when-us/22670992#22670992 . See  if it helps. If not , then comment the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Jps doesn't show HMaster. It just shows some process which have nothing to do with HBase or ZooKeeper.
And here's my hbase-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/giovanni/HBase_store/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/giovanni/HBase_store/hbase</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```