# fail to connect to Hbase with java api

Tags: java, api, hadoop, hbase

Can I use java api to connect to Hbase in a standalone mode(without Hadoop)?

Here is my code, and I was wondering how to make it work. Should I set some property to the variable 'config'?

I have these installed locally : Hbase-0.98.0   Hadoop 2.2.0

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;


public class MyLittleHBaseClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // maybe I should do some configuration here, but I don't know how
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    HTable table = new HTable(config, "myLittleHBaseTable");

    Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));

    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"),
      Bytes.toBytes("Some Value"));

    table.put(p);

    Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));
    Result r = table.get(g);
    byte [] value = r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"),
      Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"));

    String valueStr = Bytes.toString(value);
    System.out.println("GET: " + valueStr);

    Scan s = new Scan();
    s.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"));
    ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(s);
    try {

      for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next()) {

        System.out.println("Found row: " + rr);
      }

    } finally {

      scanner.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting this property to HbaseConfiguration object `hbase.zookeeper.quorum`

Comment: Have you tried running it? The program looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hbase-site.xml in standalone mode is empty(), you don't have to set any thing. If have overridden anything in the hbase-site.xml, better add that hbase-site.xml instead of setting parameter separately.

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.addResource("<HBASE_CONF_DIR_PATH>/hbase-site.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is really helpful to me, and I got another problem here, could you please have a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710112/get-error-when-i-use-java-api-to-connect-hbasestandalone-mode-without-hadoop