# Unable to edit hbase-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using standalone HBase and so need to remove some property file from hbase-site.xml as per the suggestion provided in -[get "ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null" when using Hbase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663484/get-error-cant-get-master-address-from-zookeeper-znode-data-null-when-us)

But when I try to edit the "hbase-site.xml" file, it says only read-level permission. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, hbase-site.xml will allow the write permission to hbase / root users only, all the other users just have the Read permissions. Below is the sample file with the permissions.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 hbase hadoop 4832 Apr 20  2016 hbase-site.xml
```

To modify the file, switch to root or hbase user and modify. You can switch to other users using:

```
hbase user: sudo su <user> (sudo su hbase) 
root: sudo su
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your  username .
Your current user has no authority
you can use

```
 whoami
```

show  file ownership & authority  use

```
  ls -l
```

result like

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  usergroup  size  date  filename
```

The group is divided into: user, group, other
The files are divided into: reader:r (4), write:w (2), execute:x (1).

you can use `sudo` or

```
chown usename:usergroup filename  
chmod 666 filename
```