# HBase with Kafka and Zookeeper - ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am working on an application which have following flow :

KAFKA PRODUCER --> SPARK STREAMING APPLICATION (KAFKA CONSUMER) --> HBASE --> PYTHON VIZ.

I have Spark, Kafka 2.3.0, HBase 1.3.5 and Zookeeper 3.4.13 installed.
Spark, Kafka and Zookeeper are working successfully.

I'm having difficulty connecting HBase to Zookeeper.

1. I am using HBase in pseudo distributed mode. Below is my `hbase- 
   site.xml` :

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/var/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
     <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

2. I have set **HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false**  in hbase-env.sh as I am 
   running Zookeeper server separately from *kafka/bin/zookeeper-server- 
   start* .
3. `jps` command output:

```
4656 QuorumPeerMain
2977 HRegionServer
6083 NameNode
6694 Jps
6330 SecondaryNameNode
6524 ResourceManager
6191 DataNode
```

I am following below steps :

- Starting hadoop
- Starting Zookeeper server
  *kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start /usr/local/Cellar/apache-zookeeper-3.5.5-bin/conf/zoo.cfg*
- Running KAFKA Producer and consumer application.

In HBase shell the `list` command returns the following error :

**Error - Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null**

I am stuck at this point. Please help me to understand that what I am missing.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663484/get-error-cant-get-master-address-from-zookeeper-znode-data-null-when-us

Comment: @Christian Hey , Unfortunately the posted link didn't answer my problem :)

Comment: You might want to read some code, seems that there is a zookeeper.znode.master which registers an address which seems pretty important. https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/025ddce868eb06b4072b5152c5ffae5a01e7ae30/hbase-zookeeper/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/zookeeper/MasterAddressTracker.java#L156

Comment: I assume a restart does not help. Have you got more logs or is the error the only message. Looking in some forums I have seen that many many people have or had the same issue / error message. I hope there is a solution for you.

Comment: @Christian for the time being, I am storing data in MongoDB. I will work on this problem after completing this project and will update the solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are many many answers in the link posted on top of the comments. Maybe you should start here: Look into the hbase log in /var/log/hbase to find out what is causing the issue.